# Does the effect that reduces your minimum health stack?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact wording of the effect in game. It's something along the lines of "Don't die until health reaches:".

I assume the way this works is that your health can drop below 0, and instead of dying at 0, you die at the number the item mentions.

However, I have two items, each of which have this attribute with a value of -40. If I equip both at the same time, does that mean I won't die until my health reaches -80? Or is it just an effect that you either have or don't, and it's still -40 even with both equipped?

I couldn't find this stat on my character screen, so I wasn't sure if it stacked, and it's not exactly the kind of thing I want to science myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find this "stat" on your character screen because it's **not** a stat at all, but an effect, known as *Heroism*.

And as such, it does not stack with each other, you'll still die at -40 Health even with both items equipped. If you unequip the items while your health is negative, you'll die instantly.

For more information on this and more effects, refer to [this page](http://te4.org/wiki/Effect) on the Official Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the Heroism infusion? It's an infusion. And since infusions work like talents, I'm afraid they won't stack.